# Math.cos is returning wrong value?

Tags: python

The `cos of 45` should be returning a value of: `sqr(2)/2`

When I checked the following:
`test = math.cos(45)`
it returns the value of: `0.5253`

So I thought I had to convert it to degrees: `test = math.degrees(math.cos(45))` but instead it returns the value of: `30.0987`
I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I just want the `cos(45)` to return a value of: `sqr(2)/2` just as my calculator does ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `math.cos(math.radians(45))`. Trigonometric functions need their arguments in radians, Blender also uses radians internally.